# Flutter list of strings not reacting to if null operator when populated by firestore Document snapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to map a firebase DocumentSnapshot to a custom class ,'Comp', shown below. If i create an empty document on firebase and try to map to the comp class I get a null instance of this class.

I tried to take care of the possibility of null values from Firebase using ?? and ternary operators.

An important piece of information is that this problem resolves itself if I remove the imageCaroselList from the comp class.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Comp {



final String id;
  final String compName;
  final String locationCityState;
  final String hostSiteGymName;
  final String hostSiteAddress;
  final String contactEmail;
  final String contactPhone;
  final String featureImageURL;
  final String date;
  final String infoText;
  final List<String> imageCaroselList;




Comp({ 
  this.id,
  this.compName, 
  this.locationCityState, 
  this.hostSiteGymName, 
  this.hostSiteAddress,
  this.contactEmail,
  this.contactPhone,
  this.featureImageURL,
  this.date,
  this.infoText,
  this.imageCaroselList

   });



factory Comp.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map data = doc.data;
return Comp(
  id: doc.documentID,
  compName: data['Comp Name'] ?? 'Comp Name',
  locationCityState: data['Location City, State'] ?? 'Location City, State',
  hostSiteGymName: data['Host Site/Gym Name'] ?? 'Host Site/Gym Name',
  hostSiteAddress: data['Host Site/Gym Address'] ?? 'Host Site/Gym Address',
  contactEmail: data['Contact Email'] ?? 'Contact Email',
  contactPhone: data['Contact Phone'] ?? 'Contact Phone',
  featureImageURL: data['Feature Image URL'] ?? 'Feature Image URL',
  date: data['Date'] ?? 'Date',
  infoText: data['Main Info Text'] ?? 'No info Text Available',
  imageCaroselList: List.from(data['Image Carosel URL List']).isEmpty || List.from(data['Image Carosel URL List']) == null ? []: List.from(data['Image Carosel URL List']) ,
);
  }

}
```

The code below is where it is rendering as null:

```
class _UpcomingCompsTabState extends State<UpcomingCompsTab> {
  final DatabaseService _db = DatabaseService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //subscribing to a stream of comp items
    return StreamBuilder<List<Comp>>(
        stream: _db.comps,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //converting the snapshot of list to an actual list
          List<Comp> compList = snapshot.data;
          if (compList != null) {
```

It may also be worth noting that if the document is complete ,not empty, on firebase this code works just fine